# Allowing all calls on Do Not Disturb

Tags: iphone, ios, email, notifications, do-not-disturb

I have an iPhone for work and I want to set Do Not Disturb to block all notifications except calls. I do not prioritize reading emails and messages outside of normal working hours, but if the phone rings, I will answer it.

I want all calls to ring, not just vibrate, and I do not want to set Emergency Bypass for contacts as I occasionally get calls from external contractors who I don't know. How do I set this up?

On Android, this is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should be easy.

`Settings` > `Do Not Disturb` > `Allow Calls From` > `Anyone`

[image]

If you want your phone to ring instead of vibrating, you should leave the mute button on the left side deactivated.

Comment: Hi Darwin. Thanks for that. The mute button was activated and didn't realize.